# ansible cannot authenticate target directory

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, circleci, packer

I'm trying to use packer to call ansible in circleci. 
I'm running ansible version 2.9.4, packer 1.5.1, and alpine edge. When i run `packer build base_ami` on this script 

`"provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "ansible",
      "playbook_file": "/root/project/Packer_file/ansible/main.yml",
      "extra_arguments": [
        "--extra-vars", "BUNDLE_VERSION={{user`ami_bundle_version`}}"
      ]
    }
  ]`

I get the following error in ansible

`` Ruby_Node base golden-ami: PLAY [Setup Golden AMIs] *******************************************************
    Ruby_Node base golden-ami:
    Ruby_Node base golden-ami: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    Ruby_Node base golden-ami: fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580765671.6926048-217217096224757 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1580765671.6926048-217217096224757=\"` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580765671.6926048-217217096224757 `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}
    Ruby_Node base golden-ami:
    Ruby_Node base golden-ami: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    Ruby_Node base golden-ami: default                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0 ``

Does anyone know what is wrong in here?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by add user

```
"provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "ansible",
      "playbook_file": "/root/project/Packer_file/ansible/main.yml",
      "user": "ansible",
      "extra_arguments": [
        "--extra-vars", "BUNDLE_VERSION={{userami_bundle_version}}"
      ]
    }
  ]
```